# std::condition_variable::wait not releasing lock on RaspberryPi

Tags: c++, multithreading, raspberry-pi, g++, condition-variable

I have a project cross compiled on Ubuntu for RaspberryPi(3) with tools from git://github.com/raspberrypi/tools.git. I wanted to use thread synchronization with [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), but [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) seems not to release the lock on `mutex` provided to it, as described in the docs. Here is the simplified code that reproduces the issue on RaspberryPi (there is excessive logging to better visualize the issue):

```
int main(int argc, const char* args[])
{
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex m;
    bool ok = false;

    std::cout << "locking in main" << std::endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    std::cout << "locked in main" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "starting thread" << std::endl;
    std::thread t([&cv, &m, &ok]() {
        std::cout << "locking in thread" << std::endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        std::cout << "locked in thread" << std::endl;
        ok = true;

        std::cout << "unlocking in thread" << std::endl;
        lock.unlock();
        std::cout << "signalling cv" << std::endl;
        cv.notify_one();
    });

    std::cout << "starting wait" << std::endl;
    bool success = cv.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::seconds(10), [&ok]{ return ok; });
    std::cout << "finished waiting: " << success << std::endl;

    std::cout << "unlocking in main" << std::endl;
    lock.unlock();
    std::cout << "joining thread" << std::endl;
    t.join();
    std::cout << "thread joined" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I am getting on Raspberry console with standard g++ linux version side by side for comparison:

```
RPi version:                linux version:
locking in main             locking in main
locked in main              locked in main
starting thread             starting thread
starting wait               starting wait
locking in thread           locking in thread
finished waiting: 0         locked in thread
unlocking in main           unlocking in thread
joining thread              signalling cv
locked in thread            finished waiting: 1
unlocking in thread         unlocking in main
signalling cv               joining thread
thread joined               thread joined
```

This makes me believe the code is fine and there is a problem with RaspberryPi cross-compilation or standard libraries. Am I missing something and is there a solution for this problem?

**Edit:**
The issue was first noticed in a bigger project dependent on boost and socket.io-client. I simplified `main` to the one in the question, but did not remove the rest of the code. It is compiled and linked like:

```
[...]
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -std=c++1y -I%SRC_DIR%/rapidjson/include -I%SRC_DIR%/boost_1_65_0/install/include -I%SRC_DIR%/socket.io-client-cpp/build/include -O3 -g -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
[...]
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L%SRC_DIR%/boost_1_65_0/install-arm/lib -L%SRC_DIR%/socket.io-client-cpp/build-arm/lib/Release -L%SRC_DIR%/openssl/build-arm/lib -static -pthread -o "main" [...] ./main.o [...] -lsioclient -lboost_system -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
```

where other object files are replaced with [...], libssl is required by socket.io-client. However, if I compile only the posted snippet with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -pthread -std=c++1y -O3 -g -Wall -o main1 main1.cpp` it works fine on RaspberryPi as well, so it's probably not the cross-compilation tools problem. Is it possible that one of the dependencies are responsible for what's going on?

Comment: How do you compile it?

Comment: The log shows only that obtaining lock in the thread hadn't been performed **before timeout** in the main thread. Have you tried to replace `wait_for` with simple `wait`? Not obtaining lock *before timeout* and not obtaining lock *at all* are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my linker command was incorrect, which (probably) resulted in `pthread` being linked statically, which due to cross-compilation, was not the correct version required by the system on RaspberryPi. As per my question edit, my original erroneous (simplified) link command was like:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Lsome_dirs -static -pthread -o "main" ./main.o ./some_object_files -lsome_libs
```

Such linking options in simple case of single main.cpp file reported an error while creating a thread: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted`. It initially threw me off, but were in fact a valuable clue.

To fix the issue I had to modify the linker command to statically link libraries I needed to be linked statically, while linking pthread dynamically, like so:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o "main" ./main.o ./some_object_fiels -Lsome_dirs -Wl,-Bstatic -lsome_libs -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -pthread
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
std::cout << "locking in main" << std::endl;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
std::cout << "locked in main" << std::endl;

std::cout << "starting thread" << std::endl;
std::thread t([&cv, &m, &ok]() {
    std::cout << "locking in thread" << std::endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
    std::cout << "locked in thread" << std::endl;
    ok = true;
    std::cout << "unlocking in thread" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "signalling cv" << std::endl;
    cv.notify_one();
});

std::cout << "starting wait" << std::endl;
while(!ok)
    cv.wait(lock);
std::cout << "finished waiting: " << ok << std::endl;

std::cout << "unlocking in main" << std::endl;
lock.unlock();
std::cout << "joining thread" << std::endl;
t.join();
std::cout << "thread joined" << std::endl;
```

Furthemore, I think that you should avoid to unlock mutex within thread, because at the end of scope, unique_lock automatically releases lock